# Import childComp in openlayers sidebar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, openlayers, sidebar

I'm trying to implement this basic child component (ChildComp.vue):

```
<template>
    <h2>A Child Component!</h2>
</template>
```

into an openlayers Map.vue script :

```
<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { SidePanel } from 'ol-side-panel';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import { Tile as TileLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { OSM } from 'ol/source';
import ChildComp from './ChildComp.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        ChildComp
    },
    name: 'Map',
    mounted() {
        this.map = new Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        })
        let sidePanel = new SidePanel();
        this.map.addControl(sidePanel);

        let layersPane = sidePanel.definePane({
            paneId: 'layers',
            name: "Layers",
            icon: '<i class="fg-regular-shape-pt"></i>'
        });

        layersPane.addWidgetElement(this.ChildComp)

    }
}
</script>

<style>
.ol-side-panel-tabs, .ol-side-panel-tabs > button, .ol-side-panel-tabs > button.active {
  color: #8A1946;
  background-color: #f9f6ed;
}

.ol-side-panel-tabs > button:hover {
  color:#f9f6ed;
  background-color: #8A1946;
}

.ol-side-panel-content {
  background-color:#f9f6ed ;
}

.ol-side-panel-close:hover {
  color: #8A1946;
}

</style>
```

I can't use vue  function as it's not a vue module so i tried to implement the childComponent using this line : `layersPane.addWidgetElement(this.ChildComp)` but it gives me the following error : "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Any idea on how to correct it ?

**EDIT 1**

Following RAJKUMAR samra's reply I tried to implement the Vue.extend method but it no longer exists in vue3. So I tried the createApp() method like this :

```
<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { SidePanel } from 'ol-side-panel';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import { Tile as TileLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { OSM } from 'ol/source';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const ChildComp = {
  template: '<p>A Child Component!</p>'
}

export default {
    name: 'Map',
    mounted() {
        this.map = new Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        })
        let sidePanel = new SidePanel();
        this.map.addControl(sidePanel);

        let layersPane = sidePanel.definePane({
            paneId: 'layers',
            name: "Layers",
            icon: '<i class="fg-regular-shape-pt"></i>'
        });
    
        layersPane.addWidgetElement(createApp(ChildComp).mount('#childcomp'))
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.ol-side-panel-tabs, .ol-side-panel-tabs > button, .ol-side-panel-tabs > button.active {
  color: #8A1946;
  background-color: #f9f6ed;
}

.ol-side-panel-tabs > button:hover {
  color:#f9f6ed;
  background-color: #8A1946;
}

.ol-side-panel-content {
  background-color:#f9f6ed ;
}

.ol-side-panel-close:hover {
  color: #8A1946;
}

</style>
```

But i have a new problem : chrome return this error :

```
SidePanelPane.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at Collection2.<anonymous> (SidePanelPane.js:75:49)
    at Target2.dispatchEvent (Target.js:114:11)
    at Collection2.insertAt (Collection.js:203:10)
    at Collection2.push (Collection.js:229:10)
    at SidePanelPane.addWidgetElement (SidePanelPane.js:104:18)
    at Proxy.mounted (Map.vue:40:20)
    at runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2757:40
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:182:21)
    at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2731:29)
```

Any idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: Looking into this library and by the error, it seems like addWidgetElement requires an Element argument. So I don't think you can provide a Vue component to it as Vue components are objects.